# Trouble Installing spaCy english model in python 2.7? And upgrading python to 3.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am trying to install the spaCy english model on my mac after installing the program. Right now my machine has python 2.7. I have installed spaCy in the venv then followed that with "python -m spacy.en.download" to install the model as instructed on the website. When I try to do that I get the following in response:

```
$ python -m spacy.en.download
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/katietemrowsky/Documents/Desktop/machine/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/en/download.py", line 1, in 
    import plac
  File "/Users/katietemrowsky/Documents/Desktop/machine/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plac.py", line 38, in 
    from plac_tk import TkMonitor
  File "/Users/katietemrowsky/Documents/Desktop/machine/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plac_tk.py", line 46
    print('Process %d killed by CTRL-C' % os.getpid(), file=sys.stderr)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I then tried to install spaCy and the model on my computer outside of the venv which I would rather not do, but wanted to see if it would work. Again I got the same error.

Additionally I am wondering if the issue has something to do with running python 2.7? I upgraded my python on my computer to 3.5 but am not sure how to replace 2.7 with 3.5? Right now I can run both on the interpreter using `$ python` or `$ python3`. How can I upgrade everything to 3.5?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like TKMonitor has python 3.x code in their 2.7 I just ran into this bug too. I ended up modifying the local file to just say `print >> sys.stderr, 'Process %d killed by CTRL-C' % os.getpid()` for now to get it working but I can't push the code anywhere because the downloaded one breaks

Comment: Looks like they fixed it, change your plac to 0.9.4 in requirements.txt

Answer (score 1):

**In short:**

The latest version of `spacy` and `plac` doesn't have this issue anymore.

Upgrade your `spacy` version, it should automatically upgrade `plac` too:

```
pip install -U spacy
```

**In long:**

In the latest version of `spacy`, the `import plac` line is no longer in the [`spacy.en.download.py`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/en/download.py) but the [`plac` library is used in other places](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=import+plac&type=)

[`plac`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac) is an argument parser like the native [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or the popular [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/).

```
  File "/Users/katietemrowsky/Documents/Desktop/machine/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plac_tk.py", line 46
    print('Process %d killed by CTRL-C' % os.getpid(), file=sys.stderr)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The error you've occurred above is caused by the difference between the `print_function` syntax of Python2 and Python3, i.e.:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print('foo bar', file=sys.stderr)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('foo bar', file=sys.stderr)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> exit()
alvas@ubi:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print('foo bar', file=sys.stderr)
foo bar
```

And this was introduced by this [commit](https://github.com/micheles/plac/commit/46d8d393fbca8820e5cba5d1da808b65a1c879a3#diff-a008bead586cdc7e3f6e74832de8dde8).

Since there is the `from __future__ import print_function` at https://github.com/micheles/plac/blob/46d8d393fbca8820e5cba5d1da808b65a1c879a3/plac_tk.py#L1

The `print_function` should have kicked in and allow the `file=` parameters in the print for Python2, e.g.

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import sys
>>> print('foo bar', file=sys.stderr)
foo bar
```

But the `__future__` import from `plac` didn't kick in and that remains a mystery to me =( But that's another answer for another question at another time...